# Can't figure out how to find the primes

Tags: javascript, primes

1. I have a program that is supposed to take two numbers entered by the user and send them to a function. This function will be used to determine all the prime numbers between those two numbers. However, I just can't seem to figure out how to find all the primes. I created an array that should hold all numbers between the two user submitted ones. But I don't know how to iterate through it and place all the prime numbers found into a new array. I know it's basic stuff, but for some reason I just can't figure it out.
2. Here's the code for my function so far.

   function displayPrimeNumbers(p1, p2) {

   ```
                  var numbers = [];

                  var primes = [];

                  for(i = p2; i == p1; i++){

                     numbers.push(i);
                     for(i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i){

                        if () {

                        }

                     }

                  }

               }
   ```

Comment: Why do you need to "figure it out"? During your research, you *should* have stumbled into the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). Sieve to your upper limit then remove any primes below your lower limit.

Comment: Is there any way to do it based on what I already have though?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script = "text/javascript>

function prime(num1,num2)
{
var s="";
var count=0;

for(i=parseInt(num1);i<num2;i++)
{
    for(j=2;j<i;j++)
    {
        if(i%j==0)
         {
           count ++ ; 
         }

    }

    if(count == 0)
    {
        s=s+"\n"+i;
    }

    count = 0;
}

document.getElementById('textarea1').value = s;
}

</script>
</head>

<body>



<input type = "text" id = "num1">


<input type = "text" id = "num2">
<input type = "button" value = "Click here" onclick = "prime(document.getElementById('num1').value,document.getElementById('num2').value)"><br>
<textarea id = "textarea1" rows="10" cols = "20">answer</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```